# wordpress plugin: query post-ID in plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

hey guys,
maybe some of you have experience with programming wordpress plugins. I have a probably rather simpel question, but i couldn't find anything on the web.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: test
*/

function test($content) {

    echo $post_id;
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'test');  
?>
```

I have a simpel plugin that should echo out the unique ID of every post in it's content.
So on my frontpage with 10 posts every post should have it's ID echoed out.

Any idea how to achieve that? thank you!

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978524/get-the-post-id-in-wordpress-plugin/18947526#18947526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is
Use     `global` keyword to access post id in function

And also my guess is return and echo both would not work together in function

```
function test($content) {
        global $post;
        return $post->ID.'<br>'.$content;
    }
```

Comment: @mathiregister Check dude if it can helps

Comment: You should not be doing echoes inside a filter that **should return**, Nayena's answer is closer to being the correct one. Your function acts as a callback, so echoing inside that function is incorrect in the context for which it is used.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing echo and return - that doesnt work. However, try:

```
function test($content) 
{
    return "id: ".$post_id."<br/>".$content;
}
```

also, make sure to use lowercase id, as it is case-sensitive

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID might be usefull aswell

Comment: doesn't work either! and echo and return both work normally. i can echo out anything and return the content as well.

Comment: Right answer, just missing a `global $post;` and reference to the actual post object's ID, ie. `$post->ID`..

Answer (score 0):

Filters should return, not echo.

```
function test($content) {
    global $post;
    return 'id: ' . $post->ID . '<br />' . $content;
}
```

In order to look at the post object properties you must bring `$post` into the scope of the function, that's what this line does..

```
global $post;
```

Which then allows the reference to the object's ID, eg.

```
$post->ID;
```

See here for help understanding actions and filters.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Example filter.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Example