# How can I get the post ID and cat ID in a registered WP action?

Tags: wordpress

In a plugin, via the add_action() routine, I try to run a check. But getting the post ID as below doesn't work, but why? What's the correct way of getting the post ID and a related cat id?

```
add_action( 'wp', 'check_url', 10, 1 );

function check_url($wp){
    if( is_single() ){
        $cat_id = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this output for you?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463126/how-to-get-post-id-in-wordpress-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `global` to your function first before using `$post` to make it visible inside your function (this is why we love PHP):

```
function check_url($wp){
  global $post;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Had this originally, didn't work but because of another bug, thought global() was useless, lost it, fixed original bug, but then, global() was gone and cause for this question here...