# Get the post-id in Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to get the post id inside of my custom wordpress plugin and I'm using the following code:

```
global $post;
$current_page_id = $post->ID;
var_dump($current_page_id);
```

But without any success. With `var_dump` I'm getting on every call `null`.
Than, if I add to a template than the output works:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'test');
function test() {
    global $post;
    $current_page_id = $post->ID;
}
```

What I would like to achieve inside of my plugin, is to pass the current post id to one of my functions. So something like:

```
my_function($base_url, array('variable_to_post' => $post->ID));
```

Comment: I think wp_footer is theme-dependent which means that it is up to the author of each WordPress theme to include it.For more info check this -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: Where are you using this code? $post global works in single.php and in loop.

Comment: @deroccha you can also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006466/wordpress-plugin-query-post-id-in-plugin

Comment: it seems like a callback it's enough to call the current $post->ID. I made another function what is rendering in fact one of my javascript output in the footer than I'm passing back the $post global variable from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get post id from wordpress plugin, you can run your plugin in `wp` action hook, to get access to global `$wp_query` object.

Here is simple test solution.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin Name
Plugin URI:
Description: Plugin Description
Version: 1.0.0
Author:
Author URI:
*/

if (!defined('WPINC')) {
    die;
}

/**
 * Class MyPlugin
 */
class MyPlugin {
    private $postId;

    /**
     * MyPlugin constructor.
     * @param $wp_query
     */
    public function __construct($wp_query) {
        if ($wp_query && $wp_query->post) {
            $this->postId = $wp_query->post->ID;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Post Id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPostId() {
        return $this->postId;
    }
}

/**
 * Start plugin
 */
add_action('wp', function () {
    global $wp_query;
    $myPlugin = new MyPlugin($wp_query);
    echo $myPlugin->getPostId();
});
```

Hope this will be of help for someone.

Comment: Can I rename `$wp_query` var?

Comment: @la_petite_kozel yes, in `__construct($wp_query)` you can name variable as you like.

Comment: Hm, unable to change for some reason. Here is what I have: `public function __construct($rel_query) { if ($rel_query&& $rel_query->post) { $this->postId = $rel_query->post->ID; } }` and `global $rel_query; $current_post = new current_post($rel_query); $category_arr = get_the_category($current_post->getPostId());`

Comment: @la_petite_kozel ONLY in __constructor (plugin class). $wp_query cannot be changed in add_action hook.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, when you are using this in your plugin:

```
add_action('wp_head','getPageId');
```

And declare following function:

```
function check_thankyou(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        global $wp_query;
        $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
        echo $postid;
    }
}
```